# A simple question about union of finite groups

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

My simple question is whether a union of finite groups is a finite group, or it isn't necessarily true. For example, if I take a group $A$ such that: $A = A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3 \cup...\cup A_k$, when $A_i, 1\le i\le k$, are finite sets in $P(\mathbb{N})$. Is $A$ a finite set in $P(\mathbb{N})$, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is straightforward to see that a finite union of finite sets is again a finite set (actually, you can compute the cardinality of the union, see this: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion–exclusion_principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)).

However, it is false in general that the union of two groups is again a group, unless one is contained in the other. Here is a hint for the proof: take two groups $G $and $H$, take two elements $g\in G-H$, $h\in H-G$ and see what the product $gh$ does.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't understand this line: "However, it is false in general that the union of two groups is again a group...". Did you mean a finite group?

Comment: No, I meant that in general, the union of two groups is not a group, regardless of their cardinality.

Comment: Can you give an example for this false case?

Comment: Take $G=2\mathbb{Z}$, $H=3\mathbb{Z}$. Is their union an additive group?

Comment: I still didn't understand. :(

Comment: Use the group axioms and eventually you will understand.

Comment: you mean that the union of G and H is not $\mathbb{Z}$?